# A question on indefinite integration.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}dx$$

My attempt:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1-2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x}dx$

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1-\frac{\sin^2 2x}{2}}dx$

$2\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{2\cos^2 2x + \sin^2 2x}dx$

$2\displaystyle \int \frac{\sec^2 2x}{2+\tan^2 2x}dx$

$t = \tan 2x$

Any help would be appreciated.
$\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx} = (\sec^2 2x)2$

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{2+t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{t}{\sqrt2}\bigg)$ + C

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\tan2x}{\sqrt2}\bigg)$ + C

But the answer given in my book is,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt2}{\tan 2x}\bigg)$+ C

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\arctan(x)+ \arctan(1/x)$ is constant for $x>0$  (and for $x<0$).

Comment: See the duplicate. But I also wonder how you did the first step? I doesn't look right.

Comment: I wrote $(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)^2 - 2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x$.

Comment: @RobertZ But that still doesn't answer my question.